# Replacing characters using javascript replace and substring

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string in js like this:

```
var frmSearch ="LoginID=:PersonName=:CallIDNumber=:NumberCalledTo=%2B92+3344038368:NumberCalledFrom=%2B92+3344038368:Notes="
```

I want to remove space (%2B) and replace + with ~ from NumberCalledTo and NumberCalledFrom. numbers can be of different length and LoginID, Call ID number can have value or be empty. Notes can be empty or have value.

I tried this but it is not working:

```
 frmSearch = frmSearch.substr(0, frmSearch.length - s.length);
        var NumberCalledTo = frmSearch.substr(frmSearch.indexOf(":NumberCalledTo"), frmSearch.indexOf(":NumberCalledFrom"));
        NumberCalledTo = NumberCalledTo.replace('+', '').replace('%2B', '~');
        var NumberCalledFrom = frmSearch.substr(frmSearch.indexOf(":NumberCalledFrom"), frmSearch.indexOf(":Notes"));
        NumberCalledFrom = NumberCalledFrom.replace('+', '').replace('%2B', '~');
```

Please suggest how to do it ?

Comment: First thing to do would be wrap you frmSearch in "" to make it a string. Like frmSearch = "fjfjfjfj"

Comment: what do you mean by `replace + with ~ from NumberCalledTo and NumberCalledFrom`

Comment: Your code removes `+` and replaces `%2B` with `~`; knowing that, you should be able to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to replace `%2B` and `+` in values of `NumberCalledTo/From` (and not for example in value of CallIDNumber etc), you can use some regular expressions, like that:

```
var str = "LoginID=:PersonName=:CallIDNumber=:NumberCalledTo=%2B92+33440+38368:NumberCalledFrom=%2B92+3344038368:Notes=";
var regex = new RegExp("\\bNumberCalled(To|From)=[^:$]*?[:$]", "g");
str = str.replace(regex, function(match) {
    return match.replace(/%2B/g, "").replace(/\+/g, "~");
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Eax68/)**.

*Short Explanation*:
The first `replace(...)` just isolates the "NumberCalledTo=" and "NumberCalledFrom=" parts, so nothing else is unintentionally replaced.
The senocd and third `replace(...)` just replace all occurences of `%2B` and `+` respectively.
(For more info about Regular Expressions **[here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)**.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var frmSearch ="LoginID=:PersonName=:CallIDNumber=:NumberCalledTo=%2B92+3344038368:NumberCalledFrom=%2B92+3344038368:Notes=";

var r = frmSearch.replace(/\+/g,'~').replace(/%2B/g,'+');

alert(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mystring = 'LoginID=:PersonName=:CallIDNumber=:NumberCalledTo=%2B92+3344038368:NumberCalledFrom=%2B92+3344038368:Notes=';
var newString1 = mystring.replace(/%2B/g, "~");
var newString2 = newString1.replace(/[+\-]/g, " ");
```

Try this it will work

Comment: You can chain `.replace()` calls.